# How to pass State and City Id to controller in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I stuck in below code. I can able to save  Student Name,Email, and Mobile Number's value. But can't save StateId and CityId. I don't understand why? Please help me here.
I am using angularjs with asp.net mvc

Here is my code.

```
using AngularJSCrud.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AngularJSCrud.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetStudents()
    {
        using (sampleDBContext db = new sampleDBContext())
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            List<Student> list = db.Students.ToList();
            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    public JsonResult GetStates()
    {
        using (sampleDBContext db = new sampleDBContext())
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            List<State> list = db.States.ToList();
            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    public JsonResult GetCities(int? StateId)
    {
        using (sampleDBContext db = new sampleDBContext())
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            List<City> list = db.Cities.Where(x => x.StateId == StateId).ToList();
            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    public JsonResult saveStudent(Student model)
    {
        using (sampleDBContext db = new sampleDBContext())
        {
            db.Students.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json("Saved", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
 }
}
```

Here is my script.js

```
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />

var myApp = angular
  .module("myApp", [])
  .controller("HomeController", function ($scope, $http) {
      //load the data
      $scope.loadStudents = function () {
          $http.get("/Home/GetStudents/").then(function (data) {
              $scope.students = data.data;
          });
      } //end of loadStudent()

      $scope.loadStudents();

      //loadStates          
      $http.get("/Home/GetStates/").then(function (data) {
          $scope.allStates = data.data;                              
      })
      //loadCities
      $scope.loadCities = function () {
          alert("State Id: " + $scope.StateId);
          $http.get("/Home/GetCities?StateId=" + $scope.StateId).then(function (data) {
              $scope.allCities = data.data;                         
          })
      }

      $scope.loadCities();

      //Save Student
      $scope.saveIt = function () {
          $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: '/Home/saveStudent',
              data: $scope.register
          }).then(function (success) {
              alert("Record Saved");
              $scope.loadStudents();
          }, function (error) {
              alert("Record Not Saved");
          });
      }
  });
```

And Here is my Index.cshtml where i have created a View

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="HomeController">
<div class="container page-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                Student Data
            </div>

            <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                <tr>
                    <th>Roll Number</th>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>State Id</th>
                    <th>City Id</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Mobile Number</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
                    <td>{{student.sId}}</td>
                    <td>{{student.sName}}</td>
                    <td>{{student.StateId}}</td>
                    <td>{{student.CityId}}</td>
                    <td>{{student.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{student.MNO}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                New Registration Form
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Student Name</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="register.sName" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" ng-model="register.sName" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>State</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="StateId" ng-change="loadCities()">
                    <option value="">SELECT YOUR STATE</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="states in allStates" value="{{states.StateId}}">
{{states.StateName}}</option>
                </select>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>City</label>
                <select ng-model="CityId" class="form-control" >
                    <option value="">SELECT YOUR CITY</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="cities in allCities" value="{{cities.CityId}}">     
{{cities.CityName}}</option>
                </select>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="register.email" class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mobile Number</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="register.MNO" class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="Button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" ng-click="saveIt()" />
                <input type="Reset" class="btn btn-danger" />
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, when i click on Register button then Student Name,Email, and Mobile Number's value saved. But i want to save StateId and CityId which i couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You send `data: $scope.register` object on save, so you need to change ng-model of state and city as below:

```
ng-model="register.StateId"
```

and

```
ng-model="register.CityId"
```

Moreover, there is no need of this:

```
ng-change="loadCities()"
```

as you load cities in controller.

Comment: Yes I did this too.. but in this case StateId didn't pass to controller. Means States fetched but not cities